# word document, converted it to .htm, need to format email accordingly - C#.NET

Tags: c#, html, email

So I have this word file that I converted to .htm, and I need to send this as a body of the email.  Things are partially working.  I am able to get the message show up without any weird html tags, but the picture embedded in the html (originally inside the word document) is still not showing up. Anybody got any pointers on that? Anybody done something similar?  I made sure the images are in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best strategy is to upload the images to some site, not try to embed them in the email.  So parse your doc and create .htm, take any images and upload them to some directory, then update .htm to reference that location/url.

Comment: true but embedded images are blocked by nearly all clients

Answer (score 0):

I agree with brenden, although you can send an email with the format set to HTML easily enough, I don't think you can embed the images, at least not to be referred to by the email's html, on all clients.